# How to specify a range for color detection in OpenCV?

Tags: android, opencv, color-detection

I am using MBlobColorDetection code to detect a particular color in a video in Android studio. The problem I am facing is that the application does not detect even a slightly different color . So even a change in light affects the color detection. How can I make it detect a range of colors so that it can detect that color even in different setting of lights?

Comment: What code are you currently using? Can you attach some relevant code snippet in the question ?

Comment: If you want to do color detection with change in different settings of lights, you should probably use HSV, Lab or Luv color spaces. What color space are you using now?

Comment: sorry but i kind of figured it out myself.. thanks anyway